# Scifi animated TV series - Team 22 Z

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I recall this was a short lived animated TV shows. It would have aired some time between... '92 to '96(?).

It was an an action/supernatural show about an elite squad of soldiers codenamed Team 22 Z. In one episode they dealt with ghosts...in another, aliens were resurrecting corpses to use as soldiers to invade earth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [Bureau of Alien Detectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bureau_of_Alien_Detectors).

This question on [Yahoo Answers](http://www.assetmovie.com/amdvi_D3dC2I8kE4B1fI8.htm) states that the protagonists are

> "Team 22Z"